# Summing value of a field which is in a Wrapper

Tags: visualforce

I have got a Visualforce page which displays a list of attachments from a particular account and its opportunities in a table. In the table I have the ability to select some of the attachments (this functionality is done in Javascript on the page) and a wrapper of these selected attachment is created in the Apex Class.

```
  //Remote Action method to get the selected attachments
@RemoteAction
public static AttachmentWrapper getAttachment(String attId) {

    Attachment att = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :attId];

    AttachmentWrapper attWrapper = new AttachmentWrapper();
    attWrapper.attEncodedBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.body);
    attWrapper.attName = att.Name;
    attWrapper.attBodyLength = att.BodyLength;

    return attWrapper;          
}

public class AttachmentWrapper {
    public String attEncodedBody {get; set;}
    public String attName {get; set;}
    public Integer attBodyLength {get; set;}

    }
```

I need the ability to sum the BodyLength of only the selected attachments. At the moment my aggregate function sum all the attachments in the table. How can I sum only the attachments that are selected in the Wrapper?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Sylvie

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you doing this in Apex or in JavaScript? Either way, it should be a straightforward `for` loop with a check on each record.

Comment: wouldn't you need a `Boolean isSelected` as a property of `AttachmentWrapper` ? The VF page would preseumably have a checkbox next to each Attachment and when a POST is made, the wrapper objects would get updated with `isSelected=true` for those selected

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by doing it in javascript as follow.

```
function calculateSize() {
    var total = 0;             

    j$("input[name='att_ids_group[]']:checked").each(function() {
        total += j$(this).data("size");
    });
    j$("#zipSize").text(total);

   if (total > "1500000"){
    j$('#alert').text('Total size of files selected cannot exceed 1,500,000 kb.');       
  }

}
```